# CruiseControl.NET clearcase update -log NUL

Tags: file, cruisecontrol.net, logging, clearcase

Is there a way to send the clearcase log file to dev/null in a CruiseControl.NET environment?

Now every build that is done a clearcase update log file is created, that in the end will fill my disk.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

One other solution (rather than trying to redirect the *all* build log to `/dev/null`) is to ask ClearCase to *not* generate logs during an [update of a snapshot view](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_update.htm).

Make sure to set (on the CC.Net server) the environment variable:

```
CCASE_NO_LOG=EV
```

And no '`xxx.updt`' file will be generated.

See [env_ccase](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/env_ccase.htm)

```
CCASE_NO_LOG
```

> Suppresses log creation for the update command and other commands (`catcs`, `edcs`, and so on.) that initiates the update operation.
>
> Default: Undefined.